# Como mostrar callback?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho esse Javascript e gostaria de pegar esse callback de outra página com JavaScript como posso fazer isso? Ex: esse callbck está em um servidor com o nome "callb" e tenho uma página HTML que está no servidor e quero pegar esse calback do arquivo "callb" e colocar na página HTML.

```js
json.prototype.resgatarValores = function(callback) { // aqui dás a callback como argumento
  $('#resultado').html('Carregando dados...');

  // Estrutura de resultado.
  $.getJSON('/webpro/webadm/lncidjson', function(data) {
    var valore = data.usuarios.map(function(u) {
      return u.valor;
    });
    var label = data.usuarios.map(function(u) {
      return u.descr;
    });
    // aqui usas a callback, passando o "valor" quando ele tiver chegado do servidor
    callback(valore, label);

  });
}

obj.resgatarValores(function(data, labels) {
  // aqui podes fazer algo com a variável (tipo array) "data" e "lavels" que terá o valor de "valore" e "label" dentro da chamada ajax.
  // Esta callback é corrida quando o ajax/getJSON tiver recebido resposta do servidor
});
```

Comment: Se abrires a página `/webpro/webadm/lncidjson` o que te dá? que linguagem tens no lado do servidor?

Comment: @Earendul eu não tenho muitos detalhes sobre isso ! mais oque eu sei é que este arquivo está pegando os dados de um arquivo do sistema no servidor

Comment: Acho que o comentário era pro @Sergio

Comment: @Sergio eu não tenho muitos detalhes sobre isso ! mais oque eu sei é que este arquivo está pegando os dados de um arquivo do sistema no servidor

Comment: Se abrires a página/url `/webpro/webadm/lncidjson` no browser o que te dá?

Comment: @Sergio eu não tenho permição para entrar na pasta da página.

Comment: @sergio como eu posso pegar esse callback em um outro arquivo javascript?

Comment: @nardo_bruxo há detalhes que faltam antes de te poder responder. Estás a tentar it buscar dados a um endereço `/webpro/webadm/lncidjson` mas o endereço [parece não permitir](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54820/como-mostrar-callback?noredirect=1#comment112438_54820)?  Essa variável data dentro do getJSON vem vazio? Se fizeres `$.getJSON('/webpro/webadm/lncidjson', function(data) { console.log(data);});` o que te dá na consola? Sabes como usar a consola?

Comment: @Sergio para mim aparece { "usuarios": [ { "valor": 2.51, "descr": "14/02/2015", }, { "valor": 2.56, "descr": "15/02/2015", }, { "valor": 2.87, "descr": "16/02/2015", }, { "valor": 2.89, "descr": "17/02/2015", }, { "valor": 2.94, "descr": "18/02/2015", }, { } ] }, eu abri o arquivo lncidjson assim mostrou essas isso.

Comment: Com `pegar o callback de outra página` você se refere a `pegar os dados de outra página`?

Comment: @Oeslei assim como tenho esse callback nesse javascript eu queria pegalo apartir de uma página html tem como? Algo assim var recebe = callback(valore, label);

Comment: Você quer executar como callback uma função que está em outro arquivo, é isso?

Comment: Eu entendi o seguinte como o calbck está com os valores 'valor' e 'label' eu quero mostra esses valores! tem como fazer isso?

Comment: http://templecoding.com/blog/2012/12/05/funes-de-callback-no-javascript/